# How to use setActiveTab from another js file

Tags: javascript, android, url, titanium

I am trying to use TabGroup, then I want to use function setActiveTab from another js file but there is error.

It show tabGroup is not defined when I click button3 in the third tab.

This is in app.js

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup()

var window1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'cyan'
})
var window2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'magenta'
})
var window3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    url: 'thirdTab.js'
})

var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    //icon
    title: 'First tab',
    window: window1
})
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title: 'Second tab',
    window: window2
})
var tab3 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title: 'Third tab',
    window: window3
})

tabGroup.addTab(tab1)
tabGroup.addTab(tab2)
tabGroup.addTab(tab3)
tabGroup.open()

var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'go to second',
    widgh: Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    height: Titanium.UI.SIZE
})
button1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    tabGroup.setActiveTab(1);
})

var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'go to third',
    widgh: Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    height: Titanium.UI.SIZE
})
button2.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    tabGroup.setActiveTab(2);
})

window1.add(button1)
window2.add(button2)
```

This is in thirdTab.js

```
var window3 = Titanium.UI.currentWindow

var button3 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'go to first',
    widgh: Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    height: Titanium.UI.SIZE
})
window3.add(button3)

button3.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    tabGroup.setActiveTab(0);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By loading up the third window with url: 'thirdTab.js', you are creating a separate JavaScript context. You can create window3 the same way you are creating window1 and window2, and you'll have access to the same JavaScript variables.

To better structure your code in Titanium, you should read up on [CommonJS modules in Titanium](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium). The approach I like, because it's very Titanium-esque, might go something like this:

### app.js

```
....
var window3 = require('window3').createView(tabGroup);
....
```

### window3.js

```
exports.createView = function(tabGroup) {
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    });
    var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: 'go to first',
        width: Ti.UI.SIZE, height: Ti.UI.SIZE
    });
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        tabGroup.setActiveTab(0);
    });
    win.add(button);
    return win;
};
```

This way you know exactly what variables are being passed around, and where they are being used.

Hope this helps!